# How to use a qualifier before the word 'money'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I want to qualify the word 'money' using the words good, decent, etc. But I am not sure how to use them. Do I have to say a good amount of money or a decent amount of money? Or just good money or decent money? Can I use good and decent interchangeably?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'a good amount of money' and 'a decent amount of money' have similar meaning.

'good money' has similar meaning too.

'decent money' is different.  It has a dimension relating to its source.

Answer (score 0):

**Good Money**

- Waiting tables can pay good money.
- You can make good money writing computer code.

Answer (score 0):

**Good money** and **decent money** (often used after **It's...**) are both frequently used to say that a job / appointment / opportunity / task is well paid.

Other common adjectives in this context are **ample / adequate / abundant**

People also talk about **lots / loads / tons of money**, as well as **easy money** and many more.

The source below gives lots of alternatives.

https://www.powerthesaurus.org/loads_of_money/synonyms